# What are common Java desktop app exploits?

Tags: java, security

I know about common web exploits, like SQL injection, script injection, stealing cookies, etc. However, I don't know too much about security issues around desktop Java apps. What are good resources for learning more about this?

Specifically, I'm talking about Java apps that run on the desktop of PCs or Macs (not applets or servers).

Some issues that I can imagine for Java apps would be changing registry settings, installing rootkits, keystroke logging, messing with the file system, etc. Aside from the last one, I have no idea how one would go about doing it or if it's even possible, so I don't have a sense of how easy to implement and thus potentially dangerous it is. Also, if I understood how it was done, I could understand what if anything could protect against it.

I feel like the file system could do a lot of damage, either by deleting files, stealing data, changing settings for programs that store settings files, etc. I have heard that Java has a sandbox mode, but I'm not sure how that works in terms of running a program in sandbox mode, or how a program would know it's in sandbox mode.

What are some good resources for learning about this?

Comment: Maybe, you can start to learn about Java's SecurityManager: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-1997/jw-11-hood.html

Comment: Java's security guidelines: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html `The Java platform has its own unique set of security challenges. One of its main design considerations is to provide a secure environment for executing mobile code. While the Java security architecture can protect users and systems from hostile programs downloaded over a network, it cannot defend against implementation bugs that occur in trusted code. Such bugs can inadvertently open the very holes that the security architecture was designed to contain...`

Comment: In this article, it says: http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/java-exploit-uptick  `...In particular, three long-known issues with the Oracle JVM around Calendar deserialization, long file URLs, and RMI connections represent an outsized portion of attacks.` ... and `Java developers often assume that their applications are immune to security holes because of the sandbox that the JVM supplies. But under the bytecode, the JVM implementation itself still has direct access to memory and is implemented in an un-sandboxed language like C.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is immune to many things that a C programmer would face (buffer overflows are a big example). Firstly, make sure you obfuscate your code if you're moving it around in a jar, since java decompilation is very easily done.

Also, make sure you write code so that it isn't possible to compile a class  with your application (which may be distributed as a jar) as a library. This gives rise to lots of issues such as keyloggers and such.

Next, this may sound stupid, but, it has happened in the past, if you are saving login info, MAKE SURE ITS NOT READABLE BY ANYONE BUT YOUR APPLICATION!

Guard against packet sniffers by encrypting data if you are connecting to a server with your application.

EDIT: I completely agree with the open source idea. If you can, open source your code. It'll save you a ton of trouble.

Comment: Do just the opposite: Release your source code as open source. Closed code is death code. Write reusable code. The more often it is used, the former you find bugs. Enable and encourage reusage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of attack surface.   You have to ask your self: How can an attacker influence this application?   In a web application its clear,  GET and POST variables.  In a desktop application that doesn't use the network there can be **zero** attack surface.  A desktop application could be useful to an attacker if it runs with elevated privileges and an attacker with lower privileges  could influence this application to gain its rights.

A malicious application written in Java that deletes files **IS NOT AN EXPLOIT**.  Its just  uninteresting malware.  [Here](http://www.exploit-db.com/) is a large list of exploits.

To be honest the majority of applications you write for school have no concept on security.   Your writing a linked list implementation or some simple CLI application.